# How to interpret the results of translation operator acting on a momentum state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

I am reading the "Quantum Field Theory for the Gifted Amateur" by Lancaster & Bundell and coming cross a problem on Page 81 in section 9.1 "Translations in spacetime".

It is shown that the translation operator $\hat{U}(a)$ acting on a momentum state $|q\rangle$, the calculation is:

$$\hat{U}(a)|q\rangle=e^{-iq\cdot a}|q\rangle$$

When projecting along the coordinate direction gives us a translated wave function:
$$\langle x|\hat{U}(a)|q\rangle=\langle x|q\rangle e^{-iq\cdot a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}e^{iq\cdot (x-a)}$$

In fact, i can finish these deductions from the mathematical view. However, i cannot interpret these results. My question is :Why the spacetime translation operator $\hat{U}(a)$ will have impact on the momentum state?

Answer (score 1):

It has no *physical* effect on a momentum eigenstate, only an overall *phase* difference:

$$\def\bra#1{\left\langle#1\right|}\def\ket#1{\left|#1\right\rangle}\hat{U}(a)\ket{q}=e^{-iqa}\ket{q}$$

Note that both $q$ and $a$ are constants. Momentum eigenstates are invariant under translation, up to a phase difference.

Answer (score 1):

Momentum is intimately tied to translation because in position space the momentum operator is a derivative. The derivative can be used to construct ('generate') a translation operator.

For $\epsilon$ infinitessimal we have
\begin{align}
f(x+\epsilon)&\approx f(x)+\epsilon f'(x)\\
&=\left(1+\epsilon\frac{d}{dx}\right)f(x)\\
&=(1+i\epsilon\hat p)f(x)
\end{align}
A finite translation can be constructed by composing $n$ of these infinitessimal translations and taking the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$. In this limit keep $n\epsilon=1$
\begin{align}
f(x+a)&=f(x+n\epsilon a)\\
&=\left(1+\frac{i\hat p a}{n}\right)^nf(x)\\
&\equiv e^{i\hat pa }f(x)\\
&=(1+i\hat pa+\frac{(i\hat p a)^2}{2!}+\dots)f(x)
\end{align}
Note the translation operator has a minus sign before $a$ i.e. $\hat U_af(x)=f(x-a)$. The momentum state$|q\rangle$, being an eigenstate of momentum, behaves simply under translation.
\begin{align}
\hat U_a e^{iqx}&=(1-i\hat pa+\frac{(-i\hat p a)^2}{2!}+\dots)e^{iqx}\\
&=(1-iqa+\frac{(-iq a)^2}{2!}+\dots)e^{iqx}\\
&=e^{-iqa}e^{iqx}
\end{align}
So the translation operator just acts on momentum eigenstates by multiplying them by a phase factor. So this leaves the wavefunction invariant since global phase factors don't change the physical wave function. If you construct a linear combination of eigenstates like in the Fourier transform
it will act to shift the entire wavefunction. You can easily check this.
$$\psi(x)=\int dk\,\tilde \psi(k)e^{ikx}\\\hat U_a\psi(x)=\ ?$$

Final note: throughout this answer I used the position representation to make things easier i.e. $f(x)$ instead of $\langle x|f\rangle$. With some effort you could translate this back to Bra-Ket notation. For example $\hat U_ae^{iqx}=\langle x|\hat U_a|q\rangle$. But I won't do it here because the general idea still holds.

Comment: "Momentum is intimately tied to translation because in position space the momentum operator is a derivative" - that is completely backwards. The momentum operator is a derivative *because* of its intimate relationship with translations. (cf the Stone-von Neumann theorem.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I agree but I opted to explain it this way because saying things like 'the momentum operator is the generator of translations' doesn't make much sense when it's the first time you encounter the connection between momentum and translations. I figured this way it would connect more with the way momentum is taught in QM books.